# How loop in seed file of seed-me plugin?

Tags: grails, groovy

I use seed-me in my grails project to initialize some tables with some default values. How can I use a loop to auto-generate seeds in seed file ?
Is the following OK ?

```
seed =
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 255 ; i++)
        {
            accumulator( meta: [ key: 'id', update: false], id: i, name: "Id ${i}")
        }
    }
```

Comment: If this works then it Ok. Do you generating some test/optional data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, even I tested multiple domain update in one seed file like the following:

```
seed =
{
  for (int i = 1; i <= 255 ; i++)
  {
    CNT(meta: [key: 'cntId', update: false], cntId: i, name: "CNT ${i}")
  }

  for (int i = 1; i <= 255 ; i++)
  {
    Accumulator( meta: [ key: 'accumulatorId', update: false], accumulatorId: i, name: "Accumulator ${i}")
  }

  for (int i = 1; i <= 32 ; i++)
  {
    SB(meta: [key: 'sbId', update: false], sbId: i, name: "SB ${i}")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are these options as well:

```
for (i in 1..25) {
        account(meta: [key: 'name'],
                name: "Test account ${i}",
                updatedBy: 'dev seed'
        )
}
```

or

```
1.upto(4, {
  vehicle(meta: [key: 'plateNumber'],
                plateNumber: "XYZ6${i}7",
                make: "Jaguar-${1}",
                model: "${1}X Type",
                startDate: new Date(),
        )

})
```